# HttpClient not POST-ing data to backend server- javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, windows-phone-8

I am trying to POST data to a web server (Google app engine) from a windows phone using javascript.  The request is reaching the server, but the values are all going as null.

The POST request:

```
var payload = '{"type":"a","make":"b","model":"c","year":"1990"}';
//uri
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uriString);
//IHttpClient
var stringContent = Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent(payload, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf8, 'application/json');
httpClient.postAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(uri), stringContent);
```

If I make the properties `required=False` they are null.  If I make `required=True` I get `BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: vehicle_type, make, model, year`

```
class Vehicle(ndb.Model):
vehicle_type = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
make = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
model = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
year = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
```

The goal is to have the new vehicle added to the datastore as such:

```
{"keys": 6212341628665856, "make": "Dodge", "vehicle_type": "SUV", "model": "Caravan", "year": "1999"}
```

If I use a curl call to the server it works just fine:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "type=SUV" --data-urlencode "make=Dodge" --data-urlencode "model=Caravan" --data-urlencode "year=1999" myUrl
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use logging module and see whether all the values you receive in backend are correct or not.

first of all import logging module.

```
import logging
```

second thing, you need to use logging module to see whether the values you get in backend are upto the mark.
suppose you have a `webapp2.RequestHandler` as

```
import webapp2

class GetCarInfo(webapp2.RequestHandler):
 def get(self): #or post 
  #show all values in gae sdk console
  logging.info(self.request) 
  #or logging.info(self.request.get('<your payload object key>'))

  #your entity creation(ndb put) code here.


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/add_car_info', GetCarInfo)
], debug=True)
```

Once you are able to see correct info that is being passed from javascript client. You can proceed further else you need to figure out what's wrong with your javascript client(ajax request) or payload you are passing.

Hope this help you.!